# Cannot access all web servers from outside network

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

I have two apache webservers, each running on a separate raspberry pi. Pi A runs website 1, and pi B runs website 2. Pi A is also set up as my DNS server (and has pi B's information in /etc/hosts), and my router has ports 80 and 443 forwarded to it. While on my local network everything works great, I can access both websites. Off the network I can only access website 1. When I try to access website 2 I only get the default apache page from pi A. Any thoughts?

Comment: Working, make sure ProxyPass is working on pi A. https://serverfault.com/questions/510758/how-to-pass-a-request-from-one-apache-server-to-another

Answer (score 0):

You can configure nginx on frontend with similar virtual host config:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name _;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate         /srv/nginx/file.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /srv/nginx/file.key;

location /site1 {
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

location /site2 {
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass https://192.168.0.20:8443;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
}
```

[Nginx](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/configuring-nginx-on-your-web-server.html) installation very simple:

```
yum install nginx
service nginx start
```

Also you need to edit your apache ports from default to 8080 or 8443 for example.